# combining text with selection (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

i would like to use a selection box to select a template and i need it to give the selections/values without the file extension (.png) but i need to add the extension to the end so that the selection could be previewed. So here is the code i have, i just dont really know javascript all that well. Any help is appreciated.

```
<select onchange="document.getElementById('preview').src = this.value">
        <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
        <option value="bottom.png">Flower 2</option>
        <option value="logo.png">Flower 3</option>
        <option value="top.png">Flower 4</option>
    </select>
<img alt="" width="155" height="138" id="preview" />
```

i need it to add the .png to the preview without the .png being in the option value.

Comment: The user doesn't see the `value="image.png"` selection of the code in the actual drop down menu. What is the benefit of adding "the .png to the preview without the .png being in the option value"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

this.value

to:

this.value + '.png'

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need .png out of the value? It isn't displayed to the user elsewhere is it?

Anyway, to do this, take '.png' out of each value, then change your onchange to

```
    document.getElementById('preview').src = this.value + '.png'
```

Comment: That's why I said to take ".png" out of each value.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for something like this:

```
<select onchange="document.getElementById('preview').src = this.value">
        <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
        <option value="bottom">Flower 2</option>
        <option value="logo">Flower 3</option>
        <option value="top">Flower 4</option>
    </select>
<img alt="" width="155" height="138" id="preview" />
```

In which the `.png` is not in each value of the `option` tag, then you should change this line:

```
<select onchange="document.getElementById('preview').src = this.value">
```

to this instead:

```
<select onchange="document.getElementById('preview').src = this.value + '.png'">
```

Essentially, you're creating a string based on the `option` value selected, and adding ".png" to the end of it. I think this is what you are looking for.

However, I still don't see the benefit of doing this, as opposed to what you were doing originally.